# How to fix the count variable value in a recursive method using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data like below:

```js
const arr_obj = [
  {
    id: '1',
    children: [],
    type: 'TYPE1',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    children: [
      {
        id: '1',
        children: [
          {
            //some attributes
          },
        ],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        children: [
          {
            //some attributes
          },
        ],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        children: [
          {
            //some attributes
          },
        ],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
    ],
    type: 'TYPE2',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    children: [
      {
        id: '4',
        children: [
          {
            //some attributes
          },
        ],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
      {
        id: '5',
        children: [
          {
            //some attributes
          },
        ],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        children: [
          {
            //some attributes
          },
        ],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
    ],
    type: 'TYPE2',
  },
];
```

I have to find out the count of type: `'MAIN'`. these `'MAIN'` will be within type: `'TYPE2'`

So the expected count is `6`.

below is the code,

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const findCount = (arr_obj) => {
    let count = 0;
    const expectedCount = 2;
    const loop = (children) => {
      for (const obj of children) {
        const { type, children } = obj;
        if (type === 'TYPE2') {
          loop(children);
        } else if (type === 'MAIN') {
          ++count;
          if (count > expectedCount) return;
        }
      }
    };
    loop(children);
    return count > expectedCount;
  };

  const output = findCount(arr_obj);

  return (
    //some jsx rendering
  );
};
```

The above code works fine, but I want to make a loop (children) function a pure function. I am not sure how to do it.

The problem now is: I define variables outside the loop method.
How can I define everything as arguments to the function? You could move the function outside the component.

I have tried something like below to make it a pure function

```js
const loop = (children, count = 0) => {
  if (!children) return;
  for (const obj of children) {
    const { type, children } = obj;
    if (type === 'TYPE2') {
      loop(children, count + 1);
    } else if (type === 'MAIN') {
      ++count;
      if (count > expectedCount) return;
    }
  }
  console.log('count', count); //this is 0 always when i log
  return count;
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const output = React.useMemo(() => {
    return loop(arr_obj);
  }, [arr_obj]);
  console.log('output', output); // output is always false

  return (
    //some jsx rendering
  )
};
```

Now the problem with above code is that the count is always `0`. I am not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine: you update `count` by passing it as a parameter and by returning its updated value. However, the function returns at three spots and you only return `count` at the third spot. Furthermore, you call `loop` recursively, but there, you don't use its return value and you should pass `count` instead of `count + 1` as an argument.

You need to make the following changes:

1. Inside `loop`, replace `return;` with `return count;` two times.
2. Inside `loop`, replace `loop(children, count + 1);` with `count = loop(children, count);`

Now, if you would remove `if (count > expectedCount) return;`, you would get 6 as the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but I don't think you'd need to make it complicated with recursion. You can simply achieve the same function like this:

```
const findCount = (arr) => {
  const filteredArray = arr
    .filter(el => el.type === 'TYPE2')
      // removed all elements whose type is not TYPE2
    .map(el => el.children)
      // replaced all element with element's children array
    .flat()
      // flattened the array
    .filter(el => el.type === 'MAIN');
      // removed all elements whose type is not MAIN
  return filteredArray.length;
};
```